# How to instantiate, operate and return Type T

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function that I would like to return a CreditSupplementTradeline or a CreditTradeline using generics. The problem is that if I create a T ctl = new T(); ... I can not operate on ctl because VS2010 does not recognize any of its properties. Can this be done? Thank you.

```
    internal T GetCreditTradeLine<T>(XElement liability, string creditReportID) where T: new()
    {
        T ctl = new T();
        ctl.CreditorName = this.GetAttributeValue(liability.Element("_CREDITOR"), "_Name");
        ctl.CreditLiabilityID = this.GetAttributeValue(liability, "CreditLiabilityID");
        ctl.BorrowerID = this.GetAttributeValue(liability, "BorrowerID");
        return ctl;
    }
```

I get this error:

> Error 8   'T' does not contain a definition for 'CreditorName' and no
>   extension method 'CreditorName' accepting a first argument of type 'T'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to have an interface with the appropriate properties, for example something like this:

```
internal interface ICreditTradeline
{
     string CreditorName { get; set; }
     string CreditLiabilityID { get; set; }
     string BorrowerID { get; set; }
}
```

On your method you need to add a constraint to `T` requiring that it must implement the above interface:

```
where T: ICreditTradeline, new()
```

Your two classes should implement the interface:

```
class CreditTradeline  : ICreditTradeline
{
     // etc...
}

class CreditSupplementTradeline  : ICreditTradeline
{
     // etc...
}
```

Then you can call the method with the class as your type parameter:

```
CreditTradeline result = this.GetCreditTradeLine<CreditTradeline>(xElement, s);
```

Answer (score 9):

Right now, your program just knows that T is at least an `object` that has a parameter-less constructor.  You need to update your `where T` to include an interface constraint that tells your function that T is a member of some interface that contains a definition for `CreditorName`, `CreditLiabilityID`, and `BorrowerID`.  You could do this like so:

```
where T: InterfaceName, new()
```